# Will cors.allowOrigin block crawlers?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, cors, googlebot, google-crawlers

I have below configuration in my tomcat server's web.xml

```
`<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>http://my-other-site.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>`
```

since the configuration says that it will allow only *my-other-site.com*, will the google bot or other crawlers be able to crawl the pages from my server? What will happen if I share something on fb/g+/twitter?

Answer (score 1):

People can see your share link in browser just the same, nothing will be blocked. What other people can't do is to visit you site resources using script.